Error 503 después de un par de solicitudes en .NET CORE
Tengo publicado una API WEB NET CORE 6 en mi servidor web IIS 8.
La aplicación usa metodos get/post para base de datos de una base de datos MYSQL. Funciona bien, pero después de un par de solicitudes deja de funcionar y envía el error Http 503 Servicio no disponible y tengo que iniciarlo en el grupo de aplicaciones.  Me meto a ver si hay procesos pegado en la base de datos,y corroboro que no hay ningun proceso pegado en la base de datos.

En el program tengo la siguiente definición:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService_ConfirmacionDesafio>();
var app = builder.Build();

//if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
//{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
//}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Y por ejemplo, las llamadas a la base de datos es así:
[HttpGet]
[Route("diasResultado")]
public ActionResult DiasResultado(string idcategoria, string iddisciplina)
{
    int diasresultado = 0;
    try
    {
        conexion.conectar();
        DataTable dt_diasespera = new DataTable();
        sql = "SELECT ";
        sql += " diasresultado";
        sql += " FROM categorias WHERE id=@idcategoria and iddisciplina=@iddisciplina";
        MySqlDataAdapter dias_espera = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion.con);
        dias_espera.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idcategoria", idcategoria);
        dias_espera.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddisciplina", iddisciplina);
        dias_espera.Fill(dt_diasespera);
        foreach (DataRow fila in dt_diasespera.Rows)
        {
            diasresultado = Convert.ToInt32(fila["diasresultado"]);
        }
        return Ok(diasresultado);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conexion.cerrar();
    }
}

Teniendo de esta forma la clase de conexión:
  public void conectar()
    {
        // Demo
        conserver = "dominio";
        conport = "puerto";
        condatabase = "bd";
        conuser = "root";
        conpassword = "clave";

        constring = "server=" + conserver + ";user id=" + conuser + ";password=" + conpassword + ";port=" + conport + ";database=" + condatabase + ";Allow User Variables=True;";
        con = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
    }

Me imagino, que el problema es que el servidor debe estar saturado por muchas solicitudes a la api.
Mi pregunta es,debo modificar algo en el program o en el IIS, que debería hacer?.
Saludos.
Edición: Estube revisando en el visor de eventos, y me sale esto:
Un proceso de trabajo con el Id. de proceso de '5500' que sirve al grupo de aplicaciones 'API_ESCALERILLA' se cerró por inactividad. La configuración de tiempo de espera del grupo de aplicaciones se estableció en 20 minutos. Se iniciará un nuevo proceso de trabajo cuando sea necesario.
Como evitar en el IIS que se inactive en el grupo de aplicaciones?, debo cambiar el valor de 20 minutos a 0 o darle mas?
Tambien me sale eso.
El grupo de aplicaciones "API_ESCALERILLA" se deshabilitará automáticamente debido a una serie de errores en los procesos que sirven a este grupo de aplicaciones.

//if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) esto es una muy mala idea.. quiere decir que tenes expuesta tu api al mundo, y que cualquiera que accede a ese swagger puede hacer mil peticiones sin pasar por ningun requisito de nada...

@gbianchi, gracias por tu comentario, pero probe antes sin comentado, pero no es por eso, ya que habilite el swagger para probar.
